# Route between two OpenVPN tunnels

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I need to set-up something like this:

```
Clients - OpenVPN_tun0 - Int_Server - OpenVPN_tun1 - Ext_Servers - public_internet
```

Both OpenVPN tunnels are up and running using 'dev tun', but I have difficulties routing the traffic between the tunnels.

OpenVPN_tun0 server is Int_Server, and Int_Server is a client in OpenVPN_tun1.

OpenVPN_tun0 is 10.20.30.0/24 (just one server) and OpenVPN_tun1 IP address varies (several servers, 'remote-random' present in tun1 configuration).

Int_Server is running Fedora21, so it has firewalld.

Int_server OpenVPN server configuration has 'push "redirect-gateway"' so all traffic from client is routed to OpenVN_tun0.

The problem is that Client(s) do not have internet access unless I enable masquerading for public zone in the Int_Server ('firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade') and then the traffic goes out from 'eth0' interface.

This is what I have now (without public zone masquerading):

```
Int_Server # firewall-cmd --list-all-zones | grep -v -e ": $" -e "masquerade: no$"
...
external (active)
  interfaces: tun1
  masquerade: yes
...
internal (active)
  interfaces: tun0

public (default, active)
  interfaces: eth0
  services: xxx yyy zzz ssh
...

Int_Server # firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules
ipv4 filter FORWARD 10 -i tun0 -o tun1 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter FORWARD 20 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Int_Server # cat /etc/openvpn/openvpn.log | grep ROUTE_GATEWAY | tail -1
Mon Jan 19 21:49:53 2015 ROUTE_GATEWAY x.y.z.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=ff:aa:bb:cc:ee:ee
```

Any help is appreciated, starting from the confirmation that routing between two OpenVPN tunnels is possible in the first place.

-Paavo

Comment: An openvpn connection is a network connection just like any other as far as network routing is concerned, don't think of them as being special. As long as your routing tables are correct and forwarding is enabled and permitted by iptables it should work. Is perhaps the routing on "Ext_servers" not correct, i.e. those don't know how to route to the clients' IP addresses?

Comment: Hi, could OpenVPN ROUTE_GATEWAY be the problem? If it overrules the firewalls setup? If this is the case, what is the best way to put the dynamic address (tun1 gateway) to tun0 configuration? -Paavo

Comment: Routing won't affect firewalling, those are related but separate things. I don't know `firewalld` so I can't say anything about that; I always build `iptables` rules by hand. It also doesn't help that you're obfuscating addresses with x.y.z etc.; it would help if you showed all interface info with `ip a` and routing info with `ip ro sh` on the relevant hosts (i.e. clients, Int_Server, Ext_Servers).